# From nested loop stopping loop and remove specific loop set if that loop has a content in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have several row in a table in db and every row related with three tables and every table has many rows. when i loop main table rows i also loop three tables rows now if one of tables has a content in row then i want to prevent showing entire sub that loop only which contain a value.

In my controller:

```
public function classWiseResult(Request $request){
         $students = Students::where('class',$request->class)
            ->with('firstTerm')
            ->with('secondTerm')
            ->with('finalTerm')
            ->get();

        return view('admin.showResult.show',compact('students'));
}
```

in my view:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$student->fname}}</td>
                                      <?php $Ftotal = 0; $Fcount = 0; ?>
                                     @foreach($student->firstTerm as $first)
                                          <?php $Fcount++;?>

                                      <?php  $Ftotal +=  gradePoint($first->number); ?>
                                     @endforeach

                                      <?php $fttp = gpa($Ftotal, $Fcount) ;?>
                                      <td>{{$fttp}}</td>
                                      <td>
@if($Ftotal){
{letterGrade(gpa($Ftotal, $Fcount))}
}
@endif
</td>
```

Result:

I want to skip showing result if I have a subject number under 32

Comment: you want to exclude students who got < 32 in firstterm, secondterm or thirdterm?

Comment: yes you are right but i want to show all result class wise. you can name it class wise result sheet. witch contains firs, second, thirdterm result with final achived result in one sheet

Comment: ab_ab any idea?

Comment: try something like.. `$students = Students::where('class',$request->class)->whereHas('firstterm', function($q) { $q->where('number', '>', 32) })->with('firstTerm')->get();`

Comment: but i want to include promoted and not promoted all in same sheet. is it not possible?

Comment: also not preventing under 32

Comment: you need to include student who got < 32 in any term? then where do you want to skip?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170664/discussion-between-taslim-and-ab-ab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses relationship count comparison.

**Controller**

```
public function classWiseResult(Request $request){
    $students = Students::where('class',$request->class)
        ->withCount(['firstTerm as firstTermPromoted' => function($q) {
            $q->where('number', '>', 32);
        }])
        ->withCount('firstTerm as firstTermAllCount')
        ->withCount(['secondTerm as secondTermPromoted' => function($q) {
            $q->where('number', '>', 32);
        }])
        ->withCount('secondTerm as secondTermAllCount')
        ->withCount(['finalTerm as finalTermPromoted' => function($q) {
            $q->where('number', '>', 32);
        }])
        ->withCount('finalTerm as finalTermAllCount')
        ->with('firstTerm')
        ->with('secondTerm')
        ->with('finalTerm')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.showResult.show',compact('students'));
}
```

In your view you can compare the total count of all relations and count of relations that passes the condition.

**View**

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    @if($student->firstTermPromoted == $student->firstTermAllCount
        && $student->secondTermPromoted == $student->secondTermAllCount
        && $student->finalTermPromoted == $student->finalTermAllCount)

        {{ "Promoted" }}

    @else

        {{ "Not Promoted" }}

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Taslim, It seems that the answer is upvoted. Not accepted. Please click on the tick mark Just below the down vote button. Anyway am glad my answer helped you.